# Spark Streaming Kafka direct stream processing time performance spikes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming job that reads data from a Kafka cluster using the direct approach. There is a cyclical spike in processing times that I cannot understand and is not reflected in the Spark UI metrics. The following image shows this pattern (batch time = 10s):

[image]

This issue is reproducible every time the job is run. **There is no data in the Kafka logs to be read so there is no real processing, of note, to perform**. I would expect the line to be flat, near the minimum value to serialize and send the tasks to the executors.

The pattern is a job takes 9 seconds (this has 5 seconds of scheduler delay), the next job takes 5 seconds (has no scheduler delay) the next two jobs take roughly 0.8 and 0.2 seconds.

The 9 and 5 second jobs don't appear to do more work, according to the Spark UI (apart from scheduler delay).

Here is the task time summary for the 5 second job:

[image]

None of the executors are taking anywhere near 5 seconds to complete their tasks.

**Has anyone else experienced this or do you have any suggestions what may be causing this?**

Here is a stripped down version of the main streaming code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val (runtimeConfig: RuntimeConfig, cassandraConfig: CassandraConfig.type, kafkaConfig: KafkaConfig.type,
streamingContext: StreamingContext) = loadConfig(args)

    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> kafkaConfig.metadataBrokerList, "fetch.message.max.bytes" -> kafkaConfig.fetchMessageMaxBytes)
    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder] (streamingContext, kafkaParams, Set(runtimeConfig.kafkaTopic))
    val uuidGenerator = streamingContext.sparkContext.broadcast(Generators.timeBasedGenerator(EthernetAddress.fromInterface()))

    runtimeConfig.kafkaTopic match {
      case Topics.edges => saveEdges(runtimeConfig, messages, uuidGenerator)
      case Topics.messages => {val formatter = streamingContext.sparkContext.broadcast(DateTimeFormat.forPattern(AppConfig.dateFormat))
    saveMessages(cassandraConfig, runtimeConfig, messages, formatter)}
    }
    streamingContext.start()
    streamingContext.awaitTermination()
}

def saveEdges(runtimeConfig: RuntimeConfig, kafkaStream: DStream[(String, String)],
               uuidGenerator: Broadcast[TimeBasedGenerator]): Unit = {
      val edgesMessages = kafkaStream.flatMap(msg => {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    parse(msg._2).extract[List[EdgeMessage]].flatMap(em => (List.fill(em.ids.size)(em.userId) zip em.ids))
  }).map(edge => Edge(edge._1, edge._2)).saveAsTextFiles("tester", ".txt")
}
```

Spark settings:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
.set("spark.mesos.executor.home", AppConfig.sparkHome)
.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
.set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition", "1")
.set("spark.streaming.blockInterval", "500")
.set("spark.cores.max", "36")
```

Relevant build.sbt extract:

```
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.10"  % "1.5.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.5.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "1.5.1",
```

- Kafka version: 2-10-0.8.2.1
- Resource manager: Mesos 0.23
- Cluster Details: 6 Spark Workers, 6 Kafka Brokers, 5 node Zookeeper Ensemble (on same machines). 12 Kafka partitions.

Note: `sparktmp` and `kafka-logs` are generally located on the same spinning disks on each node.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the Mesos scheduler. I'm not sure exactly why it starts slowing down jobs like this. However I restarted the Mesos cluster and now the saw-tooth processing times are gone.

As you can see here the processing times are now more stationary:

[image]

Comment: which scheduling mode where you using ? `coarse` or `fine-grained` ?

Comment: @maasg I wish I could remember which one I was using at the time. I guess it makes sense to me now that I was probably using fine-grained as that is doing more dynamic scheduling and has a higher task creation overhead but really I don't know now which one I was using then.