# Spark Streaming processing time "sawtooth"

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

When I run a Spark Streaming application, the processing time shows strange behavior, even when there are no incoming data. Processing times are not near zero, and steadily increase until they reach the batch interval value of 10 seconds. They then suddenly drop to a minimum.

[image: Cluster behavior]

Is there an explanation for this strange behavior? I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34002565/5110350), but I am not using Mesos, but YARN. I have seen similar behavior multiple times with multiple applications.